# How to set AF area mode viewfinder if values are gray (can't be chosen) on Nikon D3500?

Tags: nikon, dslr, autofocus, troubleshooting, viewfinder

When setting AF area mode viewfinder on my D3500, I can only chose 2 options out of 4: single-point AF and auro-area AF. The remaining two: dynamic area AF and 3D-tracking are gray and the camera says they can't be chosen in this mode. This remains so in all MASP modes. What could be blocking the menu?

They're all available here: 
https://youtu.be/CmO1JAGi9Ek?t=4776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previously mentioned D3500 Reference Manual is your friend,
free at https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/471/D3500.html

Page 67 says "Note that Dynamic-area AF and 3D-tracking AF-area modes are not available when AF-S is selected for focus mode.

It seems related.

Comment: Thank you. Manual's great.